# Potential BUG in ROSE package: Difference in accuracy, recall and precision in R

Tags: r, debugging, machine-learning, statistics, precision-recall

When I calculate the measures with the Rose library I get measures for recall, precision and F1. The recall and precision measures differ however when I calculate them manually. How come?

```
install.packages("ROSE")
library(ROSE)
library(rpart)


s = sample(957,200)
training = data[-s,] 
test = data[s,] 

### Rose
treeimb <- rpart(Riskdrinker ~ ., data = training)
pred.treeimb <- predict(treeimb, newdata = test) 
accuracy.meas(test$Riskdrinker, pred.treeimb[,2])
```

**Output**

> Call:  accuracy.meas(response = test$Riskdrinker, predicted =
>   pred.treeimb[, 
>       2])
>
> Examples are labelled as positive when predicted is greater than 0.5
>
> precision: 0.919 recall: 0.943 F: 0.465

However when I calculate this measures like this I get other results for precision and recall.

```
treeimb <- rpart(Riskdrinker ~ ., data = training)
pred.treeimb <- predict(treeimb, newdata = test) 
pred <- predict(treeimb, newdata = test, type="class")
confMat <- table(test$Riskdrinker, pred)

#Precision
message("Precision: ", specify_decimal(confMat[1,1] / (confMat[1,1] + confMat[2,1])*100, 1), " %")


#Recall
message("Recall: ", specify_decimal(confMat[1] / (confMat[1] + confMat[1,2])*100, 1), " %")

#Accuracy
message("Accuracy: ", specify_decimal((confMat[1]+confMat[2,2]) / (confMat[1] + confMat[1,2] + confMat[2,1] + confMat[2,2])*100, 1), " %")
```

## Or like this. Same same.

accuracy <- sum(diag(confMat))/sum(confMat)

This results in:

> - Precision: 76.9 %
> - Recall: 69.8 %
> - Accuracy: 89.0 %

The main difference from the codes are that I use type="class" in one of the cases, but what makes that for difference? Can you get a matrix from Rose aswell?
I would say that this is a reproducible example unless I give away my dataset ofc.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some experiments with the Rose package and found that they indeed did it wrong.

Here is some prints from their .meas function:

```
negatives: 21.8284728768508
n.negatives 45
postives 135.677199132703
n.positives 155
TP: 143
FP 16
TN 29
FN 12
```

Compares to my table a confusion matrix

```
pred <- predict(treeimb, newdata = test, type="class")
confMat <- table(pred, test$Riskdrinker)

          Reference
Prediction  Ja Nej
       Ja   29  12
       Nej  16 143
```

What we can see is that their TP and TN is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `ROSE` library has a bug then:

> precision: 0.919 recall: 0.943 F: 0.465

is clearly inconsistent because `max(p,r) >= f >= min(p,r)`

Maybe you could fix the bug, and send a patch to the authors?

Comment: What do you mean with:
max(p,r) >= f >= min(p,r)?

Comment: The F value must always be between the precision and recall; it cannot be smaller or larger than these two bounds. Therefore, at least one of the F value, the precision, and the recall reported by ROSE must be wrong.

Comment: I have forked and commited a new version that is accurate. Awaiting answers from Nicola right now.

Comment: Hey Anony,
I got these results with logreg. 93 in precision, 88 in recall and 45 in F score. Are they consistent with F-score? 
I calculated the F-score as such: F <- RECALL*PRECISION/(RECALL+PRECISION)
Just like it said in ROSE

Comment: Btw, 0.465* 2  is between 0.919 and 0.943

Comment: That formula is wrong. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score - but maybe the error is simply missing the 2x - but that doesn't mean it is the only error. Carefully check if you see such a mismatch.

Comment: Well, the TP and TN was misplaced which led to different measures. I fixed that error. However F1 i calculated wrong with missing * 2 which is easily fixed.

Comment: Before I got 91 in precision, 93 in recall, 87 in accuracy and 92 in F1 (when I fixed ROSES F1 measure). This all makes sense. However Rose outputed TP: 152 which is inaccurate since there is less than 50 positive instances in the test set. I changed TP to TN and then I got precision: 59.46 %, recall: 66.67 %, accuracy: 87.00 %, F: 62.86 %. Which makes a lot more sense since the tree wasn't even pruned and the class balance was 80/20 where 80 is negative and 20 is positive.